# Do file and folder paths and group names matter to Xcode?

Tags: xcode

Some posts make it sound like a certain file in an Xcode project MUST be in a certain folder on disk, and that certain files and folders MUST have certain names, and that in the Xcode project navigator, certain groups MUST or MUST NOT have certain names.

I know there are rules governing the naming of icon files for an app. What other rules exist? What's the complete list of naming or path rules?